# keep zoom of my pdf

Tags: viewers, vscode, zooming

I am using vs code to write LaTex, when I open the pdf viewer, the zoom of the pdf document is 130%, but when I write something and compile, it automatically change to automatic, and I want to keep the zoom of pdf, how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using the VS Code PDF viewer or external viewer?

Comment: @Stephen, I am using the VS Code PDF viewer